# Set up the Query Explorer in order to get the total number of session per landing page for a specifi matching keyword

Tags: session, google-analytics, keyword

I am trying to parameter the GA Query Explorer (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) as you can see in this picture (http://hpics.li/cdf0818)!

I try to get the same result (the total number of sessions (133) for my keyword `"inconel 718"`) as shown in the following  picture of GA website (http://hpics.li/cfeacd7)

Thank you for helping me to find the right parameters to enter in GA Query Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ga:keyword`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_keyword) dimension is probably not what you want to be filtering on. When entering your search term in Google Analytics, it filters through the rows shown, so in your case you'd probably want to filter on your [`ga:landingPagePath`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_landingpagepath) dimension.

Here's an [example query](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-05-28&end-date=2015-06-03&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AlandingPagePath&filters=ga%3AlandingPagePath%3D%40inconel-718) that does that.